# How to fix $route.current is undefined in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS and currently I am getting an "TypeError: $route.current is undefined". Please see code below:

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Angular/:topicId', {
        mytext: 'This is angular',
        controller: 'angularControllerParam',
        templateUrl: 'angularParam.html'
    });
}]);    

sampleApp.controller('angularControllerParam', function($scope, $routeParams, $route) {
    $scope.tutorialid = $routeParams.topicId;
    $scope.text = $route.current.mytext;
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
        <h1>Accessing parameters from the route</h1>
        <table class="table table-stripped" ng-controller="angularControllerParam">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> # </th>
                    <th> Angular JS topic </th>
                    <th> Description </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> Controllers </td>
                    <td> <a href="#!Angular/1"> Topic details </a> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                    <td> Models </td>
                    <td> <a href="#!Angular/2"> Topic details </a> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                    <td> 3 </td>
                    <td> Directives </td>
                    <td> <a href="#!Angular/3"> Topic details </a> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
```

And below is the angularParam.html where when the user clicked "Topic details" it will show angularParam.html

```html
<!-- angularParam.html -->

<h2>Angular</h2>
<div>{{ text }}</div>
<div>{{ tutorialid }}</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to access the properties of the route which is to show "This is angular" text in my angularParam.html

Can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a plunkr . something like https://plnkr.co/edit/R4xBzD9jrcrQbvFjyYam?p=preview ??Also, whats `angular-route` version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

So two things:

1. By having the same controller being applied to the table element it is not on a route and thus does not have a `$route`. So the `ng-controller` can be removed from there.
2. You need to access `mytext` by using `$route.current.$$route.mytext` instead.

Check out the plnk I created: https://plnkr.co/edit/2jmErSMSSK7lA9cZPQ3m?p=preview